# Sum of 2 different sequence

Tags: real-analysis

There is a question which states than let $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ and $b_n \rightarrow -\infty$, then find such $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that {$a_n +b_n$} is oscillating.
I am unable to think of any there were some subparts like converging, diverging but they were easy but I cannot think of any example which can be oscillaing.

Comment: Pick an oscillating series, like $\{(-1)^n\}$.  Now you want $a_n+b_n=(-1)^n$, or $b_n=(-1)^n-a_n$.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: Ohh yeah, that was quite easy, thankss

Comment: @lulu also can you give some more examples of an oscillating sequence except  the one you stated above and also if we multipy the above by n, can sin and cos function may be called oscillating sequences ?

Comment: You can post your own solution below (the site doesn't like unanswered questions, and people will be able to check your work for you).  Other oscillating series might include $(-1)^nc_n$ where $c_n$ is any sequence with positive terms.

Comment: @lulu Like is there some other example without using  $(-1)^n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it what we do is we know an oscillating sequences let's say $(-1)^n$, and we also know a sequence that diverges to $+\infty$ that is n, so that becomes $a_n$, thus $b_n$ can be written as $(-1)^n -n$, and this converges to $-\infty$, and when you add them you get $(-1)^n$, which is an oscillating sequence.